# How to get a top most values of each group sizes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have DataFrame similar to the following:

```
In [141]: dd = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['A','A','B','A','B','B','A','C','B','A','D','D','D','C','B','A','C','A','D','B','A','C'],
     ...: 'c2': ['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
     ...: 'c3': range(22)})
```

I'm grouping it by the two columns and calculating each group sizes:

```
In [155]: dd.groupby(['c1','c2']).size()
Out[155]: 
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
    d     1
B   a     2
    b     2
    d     2
C   a     1
    b     1
    c     1
    d     1
D   a     2
    b     1
    c     1
dtype: int64
```

Now I want to sort each group by the size and extract 3 top most values. The desired output would look like the following:

```
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
B   a     2
    b     2
    d     2
C   a     1
    b     1
    c     1
D   a     2
    b     1
    c     1
dtype: int64
```

But I'm failing to get the required output by using some known techniques:

```
In [158]: dd.groupby(['c1','c2']).size().head(3)
Out[158]: 
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
dtype: int64

In [159]: dd.groupby(['c1','c2']).size().to_frame().nlargest(3, 0)
Out[159]: 
       0
c1 c2   
A  a   3
   b   2
   c   2
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for a much faster alternative.

You need a double groupby:

```
dd.groupby(['c1','c2']).size().groupby(level='c1', group_keys=False).nlargest(3)
```

output:

```
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
B   a     2
    b     2
    d     2
C   a     1
    b     1
    c     1
D   a     2
    b     1
    c     1
dtype: int64
```

Much faster alternative with `value_counts`+`groupby.head`, with a different order of the output:

```
dd.value_counts(['c1','c2']).groupby(level='c1', group_keys=False).head(3)
```

Output:

```
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
B   a     2
    b     2
    d     2
D   a     2
C   a     1
    b     1
    c     1
D   b     1
    c     1
dtype: int64
```

The alternative is ~4-5x faster on the provided example, and ~100x faster on a random 100k rows dataframe (4.4s vs 48ms).

Comment: `value_counts()` is sorted decreasing by default, so `head(3)` would be an edge faster.

Comment: @mozway would you mind to provide a rough sample of how you have profiled it?

Comment: Something like `N = 100_000 ; 
dd = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.random.randint(0,1000,N), 'c2': np.random.randint(0,1000,N), 'c3': np.arange(N)})` combined with `timeit`. You can test different values for the unique number of categories (the `1000`).

Answer (score 2):

Initially, you are grouping by `c1` and `c2`, but when taking the "3 top most values", based on your examples, I think you mean top 3 *within each group of `c1`.*

That would suggest you need a *second* groupby operation:

```py
dd.groupby(['c1','c2']).size().groupby("c1", group_keys=False).nlargest(3)
```

Result:

```
c1  c2
A   a     3
    b     2
    c     2
B   a     2
    b     2
    d     2
C   a     1
    b     1
    c     1
D   a     2
    b     1
    c     1
dtype: int64
```